# EXT JS - How to get the _dc parameter from the request?

Tags: javascript, extjs, authorization, restful-authentication, extjs6

and thanks for yout help!

Im trying to connect to a RESTfull web service that uses the full URL to encode the Autorization token back to the server.
The server then compares que URL that it receives, with the one that is sent on the request.

However i am not being able to get the _dc parameter from the request!
Any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a look to the source code and it looks like the _dc param is just `Ext.Date.now()`.

```
if (me.getNoCache()) {
    url = Ext.urlAppend(url, Ext.String.format("{0}={1}", me.getCacheString(), Ext.Date.now()));
}
```

One way to get it would be to override the buildUrl() method. For example :

```
init: function () {
    Ext.define('Override.Ext.data.proxy.Server', {
        override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',

        buildUrl: function (request) {
            var me = this,
                url = me.getUrl(request);

            //<debug>
            if (!url) {
                Ext.raise("You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.");
            }
            //</debug>

            var dc = Ext.Date.now();

            if (me.getNoCache()) {

                url = Ext.urlAppend(url, Ext.String.format("{0}={1}", me.getCacheString(), dc));
            }

            // do something with dc here

            return url;
        }
    });
}
```

(this would be put in your Application.js)

Another much simpler way but I don't know if it would work in your case would be to simply disable the _dc parameter by putting `noCache: false` in your store proxy config.

Hope it will help !